# Difference between 2 consecutive double numbers(Next representable double number)

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754

I'm trying to calculate difference between given double and the next representable double(or the minimal double number adding which to given number changes the value)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double f1(double a)
{
   double diff=1.0,num=fabs(a);

   while(num+(diff/2.0)>num )
    {
     diff/=2.0 ;
    }
   while(num+(diff*2.0)==num)
    {
     diff*=2.0 ;
    }
   return diff  ;
}

double f2(double a)
{
  int e=log2(fabs(a)) ;
  double diff=pow(2,-52+e) ;
  return diff ;
}

int main()
{
    double num ;
    //printf("Enter number:") ; scanf("%le",&num) ;
    double diff=nextafter(num,INFINITY)-num ;
 
    printf("f1=%le\n",f1(num)) ;
    printf("f2=%le\n",f2(num)) ;
    printf("difference=%le\n",diff) ;
    if(num+f1(num)/2.0==num) printf("Equal1\n") ;
    if(num+f2(num)/2.0==num) printf("Equal2\n") ;
   
    return 0;
}`
```

It seems that my f2() function returns a value that is equal to my calculated difference using nextafter() function.F1() function sometimes
returnes value equal to f2() and sometimes returnes value that is  2 times less than f2().

But checking "if" conditions reveals that value returned by f1() is the actual difference between two consecutive double,because num+f1(num)/2.0==num and num+f2(num)/2.0!=num.

So why sometimes (for example for num=199.23999)  f1()!=f2()? And what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Suppose (for easier explanation), you have a 3-digit decimal float. If you add `5.00e-3=0.00500` to `1.01` and round the result to 3 digits, you get `1.02`, even though the difference between `1.01` and `1.02` is twice as big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f1` does not find the different between *a* and the next representable number (in direction of greater magnitude). It finds the smallest power of two *x* such that the floating-point addition of |*a*| and *x* does not produce |*a*|.

If *a*' is the next representable number after *a*, then *a*'−*a* is the difference between them, and adding *a*'-*a* to *a* produces *a*'. But that does not mean that adding (*a*'−a)/2 to *a* does not produce *a*'. Whether it does or not depends on the rounding.

In real-number arithmetic, the sum of (*a*'−a)/2 and *a* is the midpoint between *a* and *a*'. The default rounding rule is to round toward the nearest representable value and, when there is a tie, to round toward the nearest representable value that has an even low digit in its significant.

Consider three consecutive representable numbers 1+0•2<sup>−52</sup>, 1+1•2<sup>−52</sup>, and 1+2•2<sup>−52</sup>. When we add 2<sup>−53</sup> to 1+0•2<sup>−52</sup>, the real-number arithmetic sum is 1+0.5•2<sup>−52</sup>, and the two nearest representable values are 1+0•2<sup>−52</sup> and 1+1•2<sup>−52</sup>. Of those, the former has an even low digit, so floating-point addition produces it as the result. When we add 2<sup>−53</sup> to 1+1•2<sup>−52</sup>, the real-number arithmetic sum is 1+1.5•2<sup>−52</sup>, and the two nearest representable values are 1+1•2<sup>−52</sup> and 1+2•2<sup>−52</sup>. Of those, the latter has an even low digit, so floating-point addition produces it as the result.

This means that for input of 1+0•2<sup>−52</sup>, `f1` produces 2<sup>−52</sup>, because adding 2<sup>−52</sup> to 1+0•2<sup>−52</sup> produces 1+1•2<sup>−52</sup> but adding 2<sup>−53</sup> does not. And for input of 1+1•2<sup>−52</sup>, `f1` produces 2<sup>−53</sup>, because adding 2<sup>−53</sup> produces 1+2•2<sup>−52</sup> (but adding 2<sup>−54</sup> does not).